# nodejs - upload using fs.createReadStream, requestjs, streaming and AWS S3 presigned url throws error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

My Environment: Windows 8.1, NodeJS 0.10.0 request 2.30.0

This is what I tried based on samples from Amazon SDK and documentation for requestjs

```
var params = {Bucket:'myprivateuniquebucket'
    ,Key:'mykey'
    ,Expires: 60};
var url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
fs.createReadStream('pic.png').pipe(request.put(url));
```

and this is the error I got

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
at errnoException (net.js:863:11)
at TCP.onread (net.js:524:19)
```

However instead of using fs.createReadStream when I used fs.readFile like below everything worked just fine

```
    fs.readFile('pic.png', function (err, data) {
        request(
            { method: 'PUT'
                , uri: url
                , body: data
            }
            , function (error, response, body) {
            }
        );
    });
```

Note I followed the streaming example here https://github.com/mikeal/request almost verbatim.

I'd appreciate pointers on what was incorrect since I'd like to use streaming in multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly an issue with Amazon's API rather than your code. Uploading a file to Amazon requires the `Content-Length` header to be set. In your stream example, the length is unknown so Amazon is just dropping the connection. In your second example, `request` knows the length of the buffer and sets the `Content-Length` for you.

If you are streaming because the file is huge and loading it all into RAM is hard, then you will need to use Amazon's multi-part uploading APIs. If you are streaming but the file is small, then I'd probably stick with the `readFile` method.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. is it possible to use the amazon multi-part uploading api in conjuction with streaming. I am new to this and  just wanted to understand if it was feasible before sinking time into it.

Comment: @Newbie You can use streaming too, you just need to look up the size of the file first and set the proper length.